# Add to cart require login in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, shopping-cart

I am implementing shopping cart in my app.  Whether guest user need an account to add product to cart?  I heard that apple will reject the app if we implementing login functionality for adding products in cart. Is that true?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [developer-centric app store questions are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative to this. Just allow the guests to add products into the cart and when they try to checkout just check whether the user is logged in and if not then ask the user to login. If the user is not registered then ask the user to register. But make sure that the products in the cart are retained. You can also implement a timeout for the products in the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the solution jobins. Yes. But My doubt is can I check user is logged in or not before adding to cart? Will apple accept to do like this?

Comment: I dont think there is any problem in implementing in your way. If Apple rejects the app then convince them by telling them that the product will be reduced from inventory and you need only genuine or registered buyers and thats why you implemented it like that.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the reply **jobins**.